# SKEmitterNode explosion with force to another Object

Tags: swift, sprite, skspritenode, skscene

I've an explosion in my SKScene and I want this Explosion even effect another objects close to its , Object are in all sides .I want to give them force to run away with this explosion .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an `SKFieldNode` implementing a `vortexField()`:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skfieldnode#1654415

SKFieldNode:

> A node that applies physics effects to a portion of the scene.

vortextField()

> Creates a field node that applies a perpendicular force to physics bodies.